# str_replace doesn't remove dash

Tags: php, woocommerce, str-replace

I am trying to use `str_replace` to manipulate the output of a string.

```
function wh_alterProductTitle($title, $id = NULL)
{

    if ('product' == get_post_type($id))
    {

        $title = str_replace('Dames', 'wmns', $title);
    $title = str_replace('dames', 'wmns', $title);
    $title = str_replace('DAMES', 'wmns', $title);
    $title = str_replace('Women’s', 'wmns', $title);
    $title = str_replace('Womens', 'wmns', $title);
    $title = str_replace('Heren', 'mens', $title);
    $title = str_replace('HEREN', 'mens', $title);
    $title = str_replace('heren', 'mens', $title);
    $title = str_replace('-', '', $title);
    $title = str_replace(chr(150), '', $title); // endash
    $title = str_replace(chr(151), '', $title); // endash

       $title = str_replace(['Bijenkorf', 'Zalando', 'NIKE-', 'Adidas', 'Sarenza', 'Filling Pieces', 'Reebok', 'Nike', 'Hardloopschoen', 'New Balance', 'Converse', 'Asics', 'By', 'Beige', 'Sneakers', 'Laag', 'JDsports', 'Trainingschoen', 'Vans', 'Babyschoen', 'Only At JD', 'NIKE', 'Saucony', 'Nubikk'], '', $title);
    }
    return $title;
}

add_filter('the_title', 'wh_alterProductTitle', 10, 2);
```

This code changes the output:

```
Bijenkorf – Adidas Stan Smith W
```

To:

```
 – Adidas Stan Smith W
```

Ive tried every instance of the dash in the `str_replace` , however, I cannot get it to remove the dash..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See the differences, this (-) is a dash from my keyboard & this (–) copy pasted from your Question

Comment: Changed 

`$title = str_replace('-', '', $title);`
to `$title = str_replace('–', '', $title);`

nothing happened unfortunately

Comment: Check this : https://eval.in/749792

Comment: I honestly cannot understand why it does not work. Your code is fine, it should work.

However, `<span class="name">–  Stan Smith   Originals</span>` stays the same using your code.

It is called using the above code and `<span class="name"><?php the_title() ?></span>`

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace('–', '', $title);
```

Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

–   en-dash

—   em-dash

maybe what you are trying to replace is one of these?

You can reproduce them by using 'alt' with '0150' for –, and with '0151' for —.

I hope this helps.